# Unexpected results from a LEFT_JOIN. (Returning null values)

Tags: mysql

I'm still learning when it comes to MySQL and I'm trying to group together a question with it's answers (Like you would on a test in school). Here's the results that I'm getting with my query:

[image]

The expected results are the bottom 4 rows, where all of the data is available. The even more confusing part of this (to me) is that none of the values in any of my columns are `NULL` so I don't understand why it's being returned.

Is `LEFT_JOIN` not the correct way to execute this? If not, what is? Would appreciate links to detailed documentation as-well.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT 
    Q.question_id, 
    Q.question, 
    Q.account_id, 
    A.answer, 
    A.correct 
FROM quiz_answers A LEFT JOIN quiz_questions Q ON 
    A.question_id = Q.question_id 
    AND A.account_id = Q.account_id 
    AND A.account_id = 48 
    AND Q.account_id = 48 

ORDER BY Q.question_id;
```

The query is still returning the rows that don't match the criteria, however populating the results with `NULL` instead of the data. The expected result from the query are the bottom 4 rows in the image presented above.

Comment: move `AND A.account_id = 48 
    AND Q.account_id = 48 ` to where condition instead of joining clause.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That did what I wanted, thanks. Seems like it would yield the same results just reading over it though.

Comment: @juergend - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As told by abhik

```
SELECT 
Q.question_id, 
Q.question, 
Q.account_id, 
A.answer, 
A.correct FROM quiz_answers A LEFT JOIN quiz_questions Q ON 
A.question_id = Q.question_id 
where A.account_id = Q.account_id 
AND A.account_id = 48 ORDER BY Q.question_id
```

Comment: if A.account_id = Q.account_id you do not need to check on them both being 48

Comment: sorry i did not notice that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a simple JOIN instead of a LEFT JOIN.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html:

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.

Answer (score 0):

You first want to join the 2 tables, then afterwards you want to remove (using where) the entries you do not want to see. In this case its also better to use an inner join:

```
SELECT 
    Q.question_id, 
    Q.question, 
    Q.account_id, 
    A.answer, 
    A.correct 
FROM quiz_answers A INNER JOIN quiz_questions Q ON 
    A.question_id = Q.question_id 
    AND A.account_id = Q.account_id 
Where
    A.account_id = 48 
ORDER BY Q.question_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behaviour for a left join. It will show all the entries from the left table in the join and will add null if there is not a corresponding value on the right table.

You can use left join for example to list all the questions in your db and show those that have an answer or not. To do so you have to write:

```
FROM quiz_questions LEFT JOIN quiz_answers
```

If you just want to have the results of those questions that have an answer you should do

```
FROM quiz_questions JOIN quiz_answers
```

that will show only those id that are in both the tables.

Also you should write your conditions this way:

```
FROM quiz_questions A JOIN quiz_answers Q ON 
    A.question_id = Q.question_id 
WHERE Q.account_id = 48
```

to get wour desired result.